# Continue With CMD Commands After Batch Script

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I am trying to write a batch script which, once complete, would allow the user to continue using the Windows command prompt as they normally would had no script been run. Is this possible? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: If you run the script from the command line instead of double-clicking it, you can already do this.

Comment: Is there anything that would allow this regardless of how the script is run?

Comment: Depends on whether you want to keep any environment variables you set during the script or not. If not, you can just stick a `start "" cmd.exe` at the end of your script to open a new CMD window.

Comment: @SomethingDark I am actually trying to save the environment variables that are set. Basically, my issue is that despite putting ADB's path on my system environment variables, ADB is still not accessed by default when an ADB command is run. I just wanted to create a script so I don't need to get the path each time i want a new ADB session

Comment: I swear every time I see an ADB question on here, it just deepens my belief that ADB isn't meant to be scripted.

Comment: @SomethingDark you are probably right, unfortunately I know no better bridge for Android debugging :(

Comment: What about just appending `cmd` as the last command to the batch file? this opens a new `cmd` instance but it inherits the environment of the parent instance that ran the batch file...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you manually open CMD (the Command Prompt) and invoke the batch file by name, CMD will remain open for additional commands after the batch file completes. You cannot do this by double-clicking on the batch file, but if you create a *shortcut* to the batch file that runs CMD.EXE with the `/K` switch, you will run the batch file and then leave CMD running for additional commands. See [`CMD` at SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html).

Comment: I was about to have them create a wrapper for the first script that invokes `cmd /k`, but I like this solution better.